# What are Trebol's powers?

Tags: one-piece

According to the wiki page on [Trebol](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Trebol), he should be a Logia user, using the Sticky Fruit's powers. This was verified in chapters 741 and 760, when we could see Trebol completely unaffected after being cut into pieces by Usopp and Law. Now chapter 782 makes me really confused.

[image]

> In chapter 782, we could see how he was hit by Luffy, yet remained completely unharmed despite being hit with hardening Haki. Logia users should be hurt by attacks like these. Additionally, later in the chapter we can see Law cut his body open with his sword. This could be defended by the fact that Law could have imbued the sword with Haki, but the appearance of Trebol's shriveled up old body, makes me really think Trebol was Paramecia after all. Although a Paramecia should not have been able to live after having his body severed. Now what's the deal here?
>
>  [image]

Comment: speculation (and therefore not an answer) he could be like Mr. 3 or Magellan and coating himself in the sticky slime.  When he was cut in thirds, he is skinny/contortionist enough to hide in the top slice.

Comment: @kaine Yeah, I read that theory somewhere, but I'm not convinced. Oda never leaves plotholes, yet something weird is going on here. You can clearly see how his hand ended up in another slice than his head. That theory would assume that his hands were also just slime in the shape of hands, but that wouldn't explain how such a guy (he is pretty tall you know) would fit inside that small top half. Something is weird here. Even his staff got reassembled, because it should have been cut into pieces by law some chapters ago.

Comment: Regarding to your 2nd picture: I think Law used his devil fruit ability to cut him, like he did several times before (without killing his opponent). But you are right, Lysop also cutted him. My speculation: Trebol is logia type. He just wanted to confuse Luffy by asking "Am I really logia?". Logia have two "main abilities": transform their body into their element AND creating their element. So I think the slime which got hit by Luffy was a "created slime", not his "body slime". But, honestly, this would disappoint me if this is the way how a haki user can hit or not hit a logia user.

Comment: @Munchkin Well it does make sense though. He created kind of an armor. It is like Monet her wings. If she was hit in the wings she would also not be hurt and could rebuild them, because they are snow and not part of her original body. So in a way it does make sense and pretty smart of Trebol to hide his body like that

Comment: Just now I saw this on one-piece wiki 
[Beta-Beta-No-mi](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Beta_Beta_no_Mi):

_In Trebol's particular usage, he made it appear as though the fruit's power is that of a Logia, by covering himself in a thick coat of mucus around his emaciated body, which the opponents would assume to be part of his body and believe it to be intangible when attacking that empty space inside the mucus shell, giving him an advantage over enemies who fall for this ploy._

Comment: @pap they indeed changed the type of his fruit. I guess he was paramecia after all and law used his ability to slice him up. That would mean that Usopp missed him... I always thought he completely sliced him up too.

Answer (score 4):

I truly believe he is a Logia user, it just makes sense. I agree that he used his powers to make his mucus outer shell. I believe he activates his full Logia powers when he needs to, thereby making his coat an extension of his body. Then he refrains from using his powers to keep his real body separate from his coat so as not to be hurt by haki users. So opponents never really know what they are hitting.

I compare him to a jello mold with a piece of pineapple in the center. Hard to get to that pineapple by simple means lol.

I also agree that Law's sword was imbued with haki to hurt him. They were in Law's Room after all, so it is quite possible that he was able to gain control of his arm and attach haki.

Comment: When I think more about it: A logia user could just create tons of his element and transform his body also into his element - this would give a haki user only a minimal chance to hit the correct body element. I think it's not that easy. Remember Smoker vs. Vergo: Vergo always hit the correct "body smoke". Luck? I don't think so. I can't find a source, but I can remember Rayleigh saying sth. like: "haki user can "feel" the body of logia types". So I think Vergo, who is a haki-master, was able to "feel" Smokers real body. But Luffy, who just learned to use haki, isn't able yet to "feel" it.

Comment: Exactly. All Luffy was hitting was the fake body which wasn't an extension of Trebol's real body. Between Luffy punching holes through his body and Usopp cutting him into pieces, Trebol has to be a Logia. I also like to point out that Doffy attacked Law with Full Blight while he was stuck in Trebol. I doubt Doffy would so recklessly attack someone that could put his No. 2 guy in mortal peril.

Answer (score 2):

There are still things to clarify so far.
Right now, he may be  paramecia or logia.

**Logia** because of how flexible he can be and surviving after being cut by Law.
**Paramecia** because he may be just like Magellan who produces poison out of his body but cannot transform his body to be entirely made of poison. Both of them just produce the material out of their bodies. He survived Law's cutting maybe because of his very thin and flexible body that he could hide it in his very thick mucus.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to share these speculations from various users:
**Why Trebol is not a logia?**

- SBS Oda said that Logia is typically a "force of nature" which "sticky stuff" is not.
- His entire outer appearance is probably created by the goo and has the ability to hide his real body anywhere inside and that makes him looks a logia
- He is a paramecia type like Buggy. You could cut up buggy into a million pieces and he can reform again.
- Most people in the series tend to have a secondary skill. He could be incredibly flexible and could have hid in one of the halfs of his body when Usopp cuts him to pieces.
- Law might have used haki on his blade to severely cut him (but we haven't seen that Haki works like that even when the user part is cut he can still use haki).
- Trebol makes a statement "Am I even a logia?"

**Why is Trebol a logia?**

- Ussop and Law cut him into multiple pieces but each time without any haki or room ability being involved, so they didnt damage his actual body which is logia.
- Trebol's actual "logia body" is the skinny one. He creates the substance and it clings to his sticky body and wears the huge coat to give the appearance of being a huge target.
- Despite being skinny he's incredibly tall with a long limb. He could not possibly scrunch up his limbs in a impossible speed enough to "hide" in his half when Usopp cut him to pieces.
- Luffy's haki didn't hurt maybe because he purposefully let the attack pass through because he said  "Logia means nothing to me".

**Another Speculation:**

- Oda committed a mistake on Trembols power. Noticed that he did create a mistake for the power of Moria during the battle in Marineford. Zombies appeared in bandages during the battle at marineford just using shadows of marine soldiers.(Hogback should be at the scene to create those body of zombies and shadows was taken under the sunlight, marines should have evaporated along with the zombies). But Oda just let it slide because Moria will be useless at the Marineford if he doesn't have that power. Maybe the same happened to Trembol.

**After reading all discussions about Trebol I came with this conclusion:**

- Its not clearly confirmed if Trebol is a Paramecia or Logia type. I think this issue will remain ambiguous until Oda confirms the facts.

Comment: I changed my answer as its all wiki reference. If you have other speculations whether Trebol is a Logia or a Paramecia pls just leave a message below.

Comment: +1 While I don't agree with some, I think this is exactly where the situation with Trebol is at atm. Btw what did you mean with "we haven't seen that Haki works like that". Isn't this exactly the same as when Zoro used Haki to cut Pica?

Comment: @PeterRaeves well those are just speculations as its not clearly confirmed yet. Well Zoro used haki with his body complete. While Law cut Trembol with his arm not attached. There is no explanation yet that haki user could do this even if a part of their body is detached.

Answer (score 1):

Many are using the argument that Trebol hid within a piece of his body to evade Usopp's attack and that Luffy missed him because of how skinny he is. Trebol's height never changed. Even after losing his outer layer he was still just as tall. So for him to hide within his body like that would mean he'd have to be a contortionist with mad skills. And the angle and way he was looking through the hole Luffy made would suggest he could move his neck and body in a way that would snap a normal human spine.

In the anime, after Usopp's attack, Trebol reforms himself entirely. You can see his hand reform as it is grabbing his staff.

Trebol's devil fruit type is a mystery so far. Oda will have to confirm which he truly is. If he reforms himself after the explosion then we will have our answer. I still believe he is a Logia user.

Comment: I want to believe he is logia too,but the wiki seemed to have updated trebol's type to paramecia. So we might be wrong :(

Comment: The wiki is going off what everyone else is: Trebol saying Logia means nothing to him. They originally had him labelled Paramecia months ago, then Logia a bit after that and now back to Paramecia